# Easy mock behaviour while requested

Tags: java, unit-testing, easymock

I was thinking, is it possible to mock whole object behavior with EasyMock, but in a way that once declared mock with all expected values and results is used several times without caring about the order of the requests ?

The purpose for this is to create an instance of mock for example in JUnit test @BeforeClass and use it in several @Test methods.

Thank you in advance for any input,

Regards,
P.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are not interested in verifying calls to the mock, and your only aim is to ensure that whenever a specific method on the mock is called, it will always return the same desired result, you can configure it using `andStubReturn()`, e.g.

```
expect(mock.getMeaningOfLifeUniverseAndEverything()).andStubReturn(42);
```

Comment: Exacly what I needed, I appreciate it a lot. Up!

Answer (score 3):

I think you're really wanting two things:

1. The ability to use mocked methods out of order, which is the default easymock (non-strict mode),
2. The ability to use mocked methods any number of times.

You do the latter like this:

```
expect(someMock.someMethod()).anyTimes().andReturn(someValue);
```

If your method will get different arguments each time it is called, you can use the anyObject() method to ignore the provided argument.